# Менеджер памяти

Tags: память

Как в менеджере памяти со страничным разбиением определить общий объём памяти?

Comment: Хоть ОС укажите.

А вообще, совершенно не понятно что именно из

-- общий объем установленной физической памяти

-- максимальный объем устанавливаемой физической памяти

-- максимальный  объем виртуальной памяти для данной машины

-- общий объем виртуальной памяти доступный для распределения

-- объем распределенной в данный момент виртуальной памяти
 
.... (еще несколько метрик)

Вас интересует.

--

Или обрисуйте свою задачу поподробней.

Comment: Мне нужен общий алгоритм нахождения общего объёма памяти менеджера со страничным разбиением памяти. Это скорее относится к абстрактным машинам чем к каким либо ОС.

Comment: @ruslan5t

количество страниц * размер страницы

какой вопрос - такой и ответ :)

Comment: @eicto
Вот если бы вы хоть немного разбирались в этой теме, вы бы знали, что как раз для менеджера со страничным разбиением ответ "количество страниц * размер страницы" не подходит.

Comment: смотря какой менеджер, я вспомнил для z80 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@ruslan5t](/users/14039/ruslan5t)](/users/14039/ruslan5t), что Вы называете "менеджером памяти"? (в комментарий не влезает, приходиться делать "как бы ответом").

Если речь идет о текущем состоянии MMU, то по сути [[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto) прав (а z80 это просто шутка).

В типичном случае в control регистре CPU PT directory находится адрес физической страницы в которой хранятся адреса таблиц страниц. Каждая таблица страниц содержит адреса физических страниц с данными (командами).

Эти структуры использует MMU, если виртуальный адрес не может быть переведен в физический в TLB.

Обходите все таблицы страниц, на которые есть ссылки из directory и подсчитываете количество ненулевых ссылок в них.

Умножаете найденное число на размер станицы и получаете объем текущего адресного пространства, отображенного на физическую память в байтах.

Вообще-то процессу может принадлежать и виртуальная память, которая в данный момент не ассоциирована с физической. Обычно эти структуры организованы аналогично структурам MMU. Собственно, именно их ОС использует для заполнения таблиц страниц.

Ну, а как организовано хранение всех данных всех  адресных пространств, опять же зависит от конкретной ОС.

В качестве примера можете почитать книжку Роберта Лав -- "Ядро Линукс. Описание процесса разработки".